# express validator useFirstErrorOnly does not work

Tags: node.js, express, middleware, express-validator

I use node v8.11.1, express 4.16.3 and express-validator 5.2.0. I have a couple of checks for the same email field. This is my route now

```
const { body, validationResult } = require('express-validator/check');

router.post('/save',
[
  body('email').not().isEmpty().withMessage('email empty'),
  body('email').isEmail().withMessage('not a valid email')
],
(req, res)=>{
  const errors = validationResult(req).useFirstErrorOnly();
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    req.session.msgs = errors.array();
    res.redirect('/signup');
  }

   else {
      //save the email in db
   }
});
```

I get the following error `TypeError: validationResult(...).useFirstErrorOnly is not a function`.

I basically based my code on the example found in the [docs](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/sanitization.html), but I keep failing when I try to also incorporate the `useFirstErrorOnly` somehow.

If I dont incorporate the `useFirstErrorOnly` I get both the `email empty` and `not a valid email` messages, so I guess my code works fine, I just cannot make the `useFirstErrorOnly` work.

Any suggestions ? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

express-validator maintainer here.

You don't use `useFirstErrorOnly` function anymore. It was a thing in express-validator v3, but after v4 was released, it was discontinued.
**You must now do `validationResult(req).array({ onlyFirstError: true })`.**

If you can, please point me whereabout in the docs we're suggesting the use of `.useFirstErrorOnly()`*, so that I can fix it.
Anyway, I must mention that this has been in the [upgrade guide](https://github.com/express-validator/express-validator/blob/v4.0.0/UPGRADE_GUIDE.md#validation-result-api-changes) for legacy users since then.

<sub>* Also please remember to not follow any express-validator tutorials released before August 2017, as these are likely too outdated.</sub>